# Can't find gtk header file for vala-code compilation

Tags: gtk, vala

I am trying to run the first sample code on [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GTKSample?highlight=%28%5CbVala%2FExamples%5Cb%29) site. Unfortunately I got the following error message:

```
Package gobject-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

So I used `locate gobject-2.0.pc` to find its location and added

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:PKG_CONFIG_PATH"`
```

at the end of my `~/.bashrc`. Now I get the following error message when I try to compile the vala code:

```
/path/to/foo.vala.c:9:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I found a `gtk.h` in `/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk`, but the compiler can't find it apparently. I also noticed that

```
$ pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

yields

```
Package xproto was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xproto.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'xproto', required by 'xau', not found
```

although `xproto.pc` is in `/usr/share/pkgconfig` and the pkg-config man-page lists this as one of standard search paths of pkg-config.

Edit:
On the other hand

```
$ pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

yields

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

which looks as one would expect.
/Edit

Can anyone help me with this?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have the `libgtk-3-dev` package installed?

Comment: Yes. I think I've checked five time by now ^^

Comment: Sorry, do you have `elementary-sdk` installed as well?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't.. But it still does not work. I just saw that `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` prints `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0` so that look okay. I will add that to the original question.

Comment: i am stuck at the same result

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue on elementary OS Hera. I've fixed it by adding this line to my `.bashrc`:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```